# Where can I see who I follow on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin, follow

Where can I see who I follow on LinkedIn?

On https://www.linkedin.com/feed/following/ it says "119 Following" but I don't see anyone in the list when I click on it:

[image]

https://www.linkedin.com/feed/following/?filterType=connection (display 114 instead of 119 because in the meantime I unfollowed 5 people via the news feed):

[image]

https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/: 
[image]

I tried with Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Firefox 76.0.1 (64-bit).

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [LinkedIn help forum 1](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/10322066?page_key=hc_forum_ask&csrfToken=ajax%3A3224657085285134303&path=%2Fhelp%2Flinkedin%2Fforum%2Fask&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fhelp%2Flinkedin%2Fforum%3Fpage_key%3Dhc_home%26path%3D%252Fhelp%252Flinkedin%26referer%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.linkedin.com%252Ffeed%252F) ; [LinkedIn help forum 2](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/10328756?page_key=hc_forum_ask&csrfToken=ajax%3A3224657085285134303&path=%2Fhelp%2Flinkedin%2Fforum%2Fask&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fhelp%2Flinkedin%2Fforum)
- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNytbi)
- [Reddit](https://redd.it/gb991r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn tech support confirms this is a bug. Fix date TBD:

> Thanks for reporting your issue and for being patient. We've confirmed the problem you reported. LinkedIn continuously evaluates how features and products are used and we make adjustments accordingly to focus our resources on providing the most value to our members.
>
> I've also sent this to our product team for consideration. Though immediate action may not be possible, your feedback will be incorporated into our ongoing discussions about the direction of our design and development.
>
> We greatly appreciate your feedback and have documented the issue to track additional reports of the problem and for consideration to be addressed in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem with your browser:

- Did you try using another browser?
- Alternatively, you can try to clear your cache.

On my side, by accessing https://www.linkedin.com/feed/following/ I can see everyone (connections and out-of-network), every company, every hashtag, that I am following, accordingly to what is suggested [by Linkedin Help here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/2717).